# Limiting decimal places of a float when converting to string in C++

Tags: c++, vector, floating-point

I'm making a function which prints the elements of a `std::vector<float>`.

Working code:

```
std::vector<float> components { 1, 2, 3 };

string result = "<";

for ( auto it = begin(this->components); it != end(this->components); ++it ) {
    result.append(to_string(*it));
    if (it != (this->components))
        result.append(", ");
}

result.append(">");
std::cout << result;
```

The intended result is if "components" has elements 1,2,3, for example, it will print: `<1, 2, 3>`.

Right now it is printing the numbers as floats, of course, like `< 1.000000, 2.000000, 3.000000, >`.

**Is there a way I can control how many decimal places are put into the string, without having to manually go through it character by character?**

As a side note, how do I prevent it from adding a `','` after the last element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `std::stringstream.precision` for that.
Just create a `std::stringstream` convert it to a string and your done.

Like so:

```
stringstream ss;
ss.precision(3);

ss << "<";

for ( auto it = begin(this->components); it != end(this->components); ++it ) {
    ss << *it;
    if (it != (this->components))
        ss << ", ";
}

ss << ">";

string result = ss.str();
```

Comment: That isn't just for output when using cout?

Comment: @jaska: `cout` isn't special. It is just an output stream that happens to go to the console. Other output streams (to file or memory) take the same formatting. About the only relevant difference is flushing, which doesn't make sense for an stringstream. Still, flushing a `cout` isn't that different from flushing an `std::ofstream`. Both mean "write now, not later".

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sprintf()` before casting:

```
float a = 1.000000;
char aa[20];
sprintf(aa, "%1.3f", a);
```

---

Here is the complete code which i ran:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> components{ 1, 2, 3 };

    string result = "<";

    for (auto it = components.begin(); it != components.end(); ++it) {
        float a = *it;
        char aa[20];
        sprintf(aa, "%1.3f", a);
        result.append(string(aa));
        if (it+1 != components.end())
            result.append(", ");
    }

    result.append(">");
    std::cout << result.c_str();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the first argument in sprintf() be a char* ?

Comment: I would recommend using [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) instead as `sprintf` is never really safe and it is far too easy to accidentally overrun the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this using a [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> components {1, 2, 3, 1.5f, 2.5f, 3.5f, 1.25f, 2.25f, 3.25f, 1.12345f};

    std::stringstream result;
    result << "<";
    for(auto it = std::begin(components); it != std::end(components); ++it)
    {
        if(it != std::begin(components))
        {
            result << ", ";
        }
        result << *it;
    }
    result << ">";
    std::cout << result.str();
    return 0;
}
```

You could also use `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision` to modify the output further as you desire.

Printing the comma before the next item for all but the first item fixes your trailing comma issue.

Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/q2HJIO) of it working:

Answer (score 0):

As @Axalo already noted, you can use `setprecision` with an `ostream` to set its precision (and it can be used with any `ostream`, not just `cout`).

To eliminate the trailing comma, I'd probably use the [infix iterator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489) I've posted elsewhere.

Using that, the code could be written something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

#include "infix_iterator.h"

int main () {
    // Data that would display extra precision if we didn't stop it
    std::vector<float> components { 1.123f, 2.234f, 3.345f };

    std::ostringstream buff("<", std::ios::app);
    buff << std::setprecision(2);

    std::copy(components.begin(), components.end(), 
              infix_ostream_iterator<float>(buff, ", "));

    buff << ">";

    std::cout << buff.str();
}
```

Result: `<1.1, 2.2, 3.3>`